# CSV Load Error with Pandas

Tags: python, csv, pandas

Can someone help me figure out what this error is telling me? I don't understand why this csv won't load.

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
energy = pd.read_csv('Energy Indicators.csv')
GDP = pd.read_csv('world_bank_new.csv')
ScimEn = pd.read_csv('scimagojr-3.csv')
```

Error:

```
    UnicodeDecodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-65661166aab4> in <module>()
     10 
     11 
---> 12 answer_one()

<ipython-input-2-65661166aab4> in answer_one()
      4     energy = pd.read_csv('Energy Indicators.csv')
      5     GDP = pd.read_csv('world_bank_new.csv')
----> 6     ScimEn = pd.read_csv('scimagojr-3.csv')
      7 
      8
```

Comment: you've got an encoding problem in your csv file. Some unicode character is illegal...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `read_csv` function takes an `encoding` [option](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html). You're going to need to tell Pandas what the file encoding is. Try `encoding = "ISO-8859-1"`.